# Ruby syntax unexpected keyword_ensure, expecting keyword_end

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, syntax, syntax-error

So, i'm getting this error in the cool view, around lines 16 and 18:

> app/views/gif/cool.html.erb:16: syntax error, unexpected keyword_ensure, expecting keyword_end
>
> app/views/gif/cool.html.erb:18: syntax error, unexpected end-of-input, expecting keyword_end

I have no idea what I'm missing (I started learning Rails yesterday and I really didn't know much about ruby). Am I missing an <% end %>?

```
<ul id="messages">
<% @messages.each do |chat| %>
    <li>
        <%= current_user.name %> : <%= chat.content %>
    </li>
<%end>
```

Comment: Does this code have a typo, or does the end actually look like `<%end>`? It should be `<% end %>`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have two problems in your code. Your `<%end>` should be `<%end%>`. This is causing you the syntax error. But, you also should close your `<ul>` element. Use the following code:

```
<ul id="messages">
  <% @messages.each do |chat| %>
      <li>
        <%= current_user.name %> : <%= chat.content %>
      </li>
  <%end%>
</ul>
```

Comment: Thanks, this was dumb of me. I had closed the <ul> element, but for some reason when copying the code here I didn't see it. Thank you again

Comment: No problem. It happens to everyone sometimes. If it helped you solve your problem, you should consider accepting the answer. To see how accepting answers work: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work

Comment: Thank you, i did. I ran into another problem now, but this one isn't a syntax one and it is more interesting so I'll look into it.